# Usability of showing products and features that are not available

Tags: usability

I'm looking for research, case studies and thoughts on the usability of showing products and features that are not available, in a UI's navigation. I am trying to validate my concerns of including multiple products to up-sell to customers in our user navigation (in the majority of cases there would be many more features not available than available). TY

Comment: Can you add an example to the question? It's a little abstract right now, and a concrete example with reference to tangible items/features would help make more sense. Also, be prepared to be disappointed re: research/case studies on this topic. Published research in this area is relatively rare, and you'll be lucky to find something that exactly validates your position. In situations like this, we invariably end up relying on concepts like best practices, conventional design, and heuristic evaluation to make reasonable assumptions about the best solution, and then follow up with testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/112248/not-available-options-disabled-or-hidden/112251#112251

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, it can also be risky because the Upcoming product that you want to show may not be available at the time you estimate, except if you have a confirmation from the retailer in which the product belong.For me, the best scenario will be no product at all.